# Python code to find stop codons in sequence

Tags: python, statistics, bioinformatics, biopython

I'm trying to find the location of stop codons in a sequence.

Unfortunately something is off. This is the code I have created:

```
def findStopCodons1(orf):
catch = numpy.arange(0, len(orf), 3)
x = []
w = []
for i in catch:
    codon = orf[i:i+3]
    if codon == 'ATG':
        w.append(i+1)
        catch1 = numpy.arange(i+1, len(orf), 3)
        for i in catch1:
            if codon == 'TAA' or codon == 'TAG' or codon == 'TGA':
                x.append(i+1)
                print i + 1
mergedlist = w + x
print mergedlist 
print NP.ediff1d(mergedlist)
y = NP.ediff1d(mergedlist)
print max(y)
```

This is supposed to be for reading frame 1. Unfortunately I think my numbers are off. Any hint as what is wrong with my code?

***Edit: I forgot to enter the start codon, which is 'ATG'. Unfortunately I need to go back to my code and find a way to read between the start and stop codons.

I've added the start codon but I'm still at a loss. I'm not getting the correct numbers.

Comment: Please indent your code correctly, add the `numpy` import so that the example is self-contained  and add some sample data with the expected result and the result you get.

Comment: What's the output you're getting from `print i+1`? It might help if you print `orf[i:i+3]` so you can see what it's checking against. Also `if codon == 'TAA' or codon == 'TAG' or codon == 'TGA'` can be shortened to `if codon in ('TAA', 'TAG', 'TGA')` for the same result.

Comment: Oh I missed the open reading frame, 'ATG'. That is probably one of the reasons why I'm having an issue finding the length of the open reading frames.

Comment: If your code is indented as it is now, then it's impossible to enter the second `if`. Also, you use the same variable as counter in nested `for` loops.

Comment: What is `orf` supposed to be?

Comment: It's a DNA sequence, trying to find the open reading frame (orf)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure what your desired output is, but if you just want to be collecting all the potential start codon positions and stop codon positions into your lists `x` and `w` (actually, allow me the liberty of renaming them `startCodonPositions` and `stopCodonPositions`), that's simple enough.

In fact, it seems like your code for `startCodonPositions` is already working perfectly. Why not just do the same thing with `stopCodonPositions`, like this?

```
def findStopCodons1(orf):
    catch = numpy.arange(0, len(orf), 3)
    startCodonPositions = []
    stopCodonPositions = []
    for i in catch:
        codon = orf[i:i + 3]
        if codon == 'ATG':
            startCodonPositions.append(i + 1)
        if codon == 'TAA' or codon == 'TAG' or codon == 'TGA':
            stopCodonPositions.append(i + 1)
    return startCodonPositions, stopCodonPositions
```